# Browser Notification Push Service: How to specify push server?

Tags: javascript, push-notification

I'm trying to set up **push notifications for a browser web app**.

I found the following code can be used to subscribe to a push server. Running a simple push server locally seems to work fine, but 
**Q:** I was wondering how I would specify the push server if it wasn't local?

I mean, how would the browser know where to subscribe to just by looking at the public key of the server?

```
function createNotificationSubscription(pushServerPublicKey) {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(
      (serviceWorker) => {
        return serviceWorker.pushManager
        .subscribe({
          userVisibleOnly: true,
          applicationServerKey: pushServerPublicKey
        })
        .then((subscription) => {
          console.log("✅  User is subscribed.", subscription);
          return subscription;
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I  specify the push server [...]?

You don't.

> if it wasn't local?

There is a misunderstanding.

The push server will always be a fixed server given by the browser vendor.

It basically works like this:

- You `subscribe()`
- This request goes to the notification server of the browser vendor (mozilla, google, ...).
- That server will create a so called *push endpoint* -  just a fancy word for URL. This URL serves as a mailbox: If someone sends a message to it, the push server (still being the server of the browser vendor) will forward it to the browser (client).
- The server will return the *push endpoint* and some other information as a result of your initial `subscribe()`.
- Currently only the push server and your web app know about the push endpoint....
- So your web app needs to the whole result of `subscribe` to the application server (which is your server).
- Now your server is able to use that information to send messages to the push server. The push server will then forward the message to the client.

Here's also a flow chart depicting the flow with a little more detail in regard of the different players:
[image]

- Push service: Service running on the browser vendor's server
- Subscription information: URL of the *push endpoint* along with some keys.